# Creating Pandas Period for the current quarter hour

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, period

It is straightforward to create a `Period` object for the current basic unit of time, such as second, minute, hour, day, week, month, quarter, or year:

```py
>>> pd.Period.now("T")
Period('2023-06-29 12:34', 'T')

>>> pd.Period.now("D")
Period('2023-06-29', 'D')

>>> pd.Period.now("M")
Period('2023-06', 'M')
```

However if I want to get the current 15-minutes period (quarter hour),

```py
>>> pd.Period.now("15T")
Period('2023-06-29 12:34', '15T')
```

it does not start at `:00`, `:15`, `:30`, or `:45`. It starts at the current minute.

The most compact piece of code, that does the job is:

```py
>>> pd.Timestamp.now().floor("15T").to_period("15T")
Period('2023-06-29 12:30', '15T')
```

Is there anything more compact? Especially without having to mention `"15T"` twice?